# Parallel Producing and Consuming in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

**1. Consuming concurrently on the same topic and same partition**

Suppose I have 100 partitions for a given topic (e.g. `Purchases`), I can easily consume these 100 partitions (e.g. `Electronics`, `Clothing`, and etc...) in parallel using a consumer group with 100 consumers in it.

However, that is assigning one consumer to each subset of the total data on `Purchases`. What if I want just want to consume one subset of data with 100 consumers concurrently? For example, for all of my consumers, they just want to know `Electronics` partition of the `Purchases` topic.

*Is there way they can consume this partition concurrently?*

In general I just want all my consumers to receive **the same data set concurrently**.

From the information I've gathered, it seems to me that consumers CANNOT consume from replicas: [Consuming from a replica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37803376/consuming-from-a-replica)

*Can I produce the same data to multiple topics, like `Purchase-1[Electronics]` and `Purchase-2[Electronics]` so then I can consume them concurrently? Is this a recommended approach?*

**2. Producing concurrently on the same topic and same partition**

When multiple producers are producing to the same topic and same partition, since we can only write to the partition leader and replicas are only there for fault-tolerance, *does this mean there isn't any concurrency?* (i.e. each commit must wait in line.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If those 100 consumers belong to different consumer groups, they can consume from the same topic and partition simultaneously. In that case, you need to make sure each consumer is able to handle the load from the 100 partitions.
2. Producers can produce to the same topic partition at the same time, but the actual order of messages written to the partition is determined by the partition leader.

Comment: If that's the case, I'd just make 100 topics and 1 partition for each topic. Then I create 100 consumer groups so all of my consumers can get the same message! However, this really leads to another follow up question. Do you know how does Kafka scale its read load? Because now I have 100 consumers reading from the same partition leader and physically there is only 1 log file exists on hard disk. How does it achieve parallelism?

Comment: Right, consumer groups let you distribute the read load across the consumers in the group. Is there something specific that you can only achieve with having a single consumer consumer the whole topic? Because you're not taking full advantage of what Kafka has to offer.

Comment: The current use case is that I have multiple instances of application servers and each instance is a consumer to the Kafka cluster. My primary concern is that, what is the most efficient and reliable way to enable each of my application server receives the same data set?

This is why I was suggesting maybe each application server should belong to its own consumer group. This way, every one of them will receive the same set of data.

Comment: If the functionality of these application servers can't be scaled out having each one belong to the same consumer group is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to consumer from a single partition in parallel, use something like [Parallel Consumer](https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer) (PC).

By using PC, you can process all your keys in parallel, regardless of how long it takes, and you can be as concurrent as you wish.

PC directly solves for this, by sub partitioning the input partitions by key and processing each key in parallel.
It also tracks per record acknowledgement. Check out [Parallel Consumer on GitHub](https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer) (it's open source BTW, and I'm the author).